# How to find javascript equivalent of jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem on a WordPress site. A plugin is going to crash when I include jQuery on the site. That's why I'd like to include simple javascript code. However the problem is that I don't know its Javascript equivalent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sd').change(function() {
    var n = new Date(this.value);
    n.setDate(n.getDate() + 1);

    var day = ("0" + n.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (n.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = n.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
    $('#ed').attr('min', today);
  });
});
```

the error log (wordpress):

```
Uncaught TypeError: r.getClientRects is not a function
    at w.fn.init.offset (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.getWithinInfo (position.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11)
    at w.fn.init.a.fn.position (position.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11)
    at w.fn.init.reposition (pum-site-scripts.js?…263704&ver=1.7.29:7)
    at w.fn.init.e.fn.popmake (pum-site-scripts.js?…263704&ver=1.7.29:7)
    at w.fn.init.open (pum-site-scripts.js?…263704&ver=1.7.29:7)
    at w.fn.init.e.fn.popmake (pum-site-scripts.js?…263704&ver=1.7.29:7)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (pum-site-scripts.js?…263704&ver=1.7.29:8)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Wordpress is more than compatible with jQuery. I'd suggest fixing that issue as it would be far more beneficial long-term.

Comment: "is going to crash when I include jQuery on the site"...what exact problem occurs? Perhaps we can resolve that. Anyway if you want to know how a jQuery function works, you could always consult the jQuery source code, which is available publicly online.

Comment: If you did want to convert this the only things you need to research is how to select an element by id, how to set a property on an element, and how to hook up a `change` event handler.

Comment: I've installed a plugin "Popup Maker" and when I Run my jquery code i mean the link that include jquery, the popup goes down.

Comment: What does 'the popup goes down' mean? Check the console for actual errors you can debug.

Comment: "goes down" isn't an error message or problem statement that we can help you with. Please provide a clear description of the issue and any debugging info you can gather, e.g. console errors etc

Comment: How can i post the error log?

Comment: press the "edit" button just underneath your question and paste it into your question.

Comment: Ok thanks. Judging from [a quick google search of your error](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=r.getClientRects+is+not+a+function&oq=r.getClientRects+is+not+a+function&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.211j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) I think maybe you have an out-of-date version of jQuery-UI somewhere on your page. Try updating to jQueryUI 1.12. Or use jQuery-migrate as suggested in some of those links. P.S. it's surprising how often you can google an error message, someone has almost always experienced it previously.

Comment: Whatever "Popup Maker" is doing/does - consider using a different plugin.   Sounds like an X^3Y problem...

Comment: I've installed a jQuery Updater on my Wordpress and now It Works perfectly. Thanks guys for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS equivalent to `$(selector)` is `document.querySelector(selector)` or `document.querySelectorAll(selector)`, depending on whether you want just the first match or all the matches. In your code, since you're selecting an ID, you only need the first match.

The plain JS method for adding an event handler is `.addEventListener`.

The equivalent to `.attr()` is `.setAttribute()`.

The rest of the code is plain JS, not jQuery.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentReady", function() {
  document.querySelector("#sd").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var n = new Date(this.value);
    n.setDate(n.getDate() + 1);

    var day = ("0" + n.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (n.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = n.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
    document.querySelector("#ed").setAttribute('min', today);
  });
});
```